# loop in R - Variable with Indices

Tags: r, loops, indices

Hi my Code is like that

`for(k in 1:length(t(trd)))
...
{
names(Germany)  <-  c("ISIN","MATURITYDATE","ISSUEDATE","COUPONRATE","PRICE","ACCRUED","CASHFLOWS","TODAY")

      }`

My Code compute all the components of the list Germany. For each "k" I want to safe my list Germany into BondDayk.

As result I Need  **BondDay1,.., BondDay150** and each of them are lists.

I Need a algo which does:

`BondDay1 <- list("Germany")
BondDay2 <- list("Germany")
BondDay3 <- list("Germany")`
....

"Germany" is for each "k" a different dataset.

Thank you

Comment: Not clear what you want

Comment: I hope now it is clear

Comment: You could also save it in one big list called `BondDay`, where this list contains `k` different sublist. That's how I would do it probably

Comment: This was my first solution. But my prof said he want it that way. For further computation.

Comment: Please properly format your code. What you showed so far is not a valid R syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearer. Use:

```
for (i in 1:150) {
  eval(parse(text = sprintf("BondDay%d <- list(germany)", i)), envir = -1)
}
```

If you put that in a function, use `envir = -2` instead.